# SQLite Insert Into error on start

Tags: android, sqlite, insert-into

I created a database and created some tables on it. But in some point i'm doing wrong so the app's crash onStart. Here's some part of my code:

```
private SQLiteStatement insertUserInfos;
private static final String TN_INFO = "UserInfos";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_INFO = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TN_INFO
        + " ( \"name\" TEXT, \"surname\" TEXT, \"mail\" TEXT, \"password\" TEXT, \"birthyear\" TEXT, \"currentcity\" TEXT, \"futurecity\" TEXT, \"check\" TEXT ) ";

private static final String INSERT_INFOS = "INSERT INTO "
        + TN_INFO
        + " ( name, surname, mail, password, birthyear, currentcity, futurecity, check ) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    this.ctx = context;

    DBOpenHelper db = new DBOpenHelper(ctx);
    database = db.getWritableDatabase();

    insertUserInfos = database.compileStatement(INSERT_INFOS);
}

private class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_INFO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

}
```

And i'm getting this error:

06-27 22:42:01.870: E/AndroidRuntime(16550): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "check": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO UserInfos ( name, surname, mail, password, birthyear, currentcity, futurecity, check ) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

I've check bunch of times, but i couldn't see any error on this line. Any help would be so nice.

Comment: This might be (I'm not positive) because some of your column names are reserved keywords in SQLIte (list here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Try putting square-brackets [ ] or double-quotes " " around your column names in the INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Hell yeah! =) Thanks a lot. I've just overlooked that "CHECK" was a keyword =) Simply, i've changed the word as "checkFlag" so it's not a keyword anymore, and problem's solved! =)

Comment: By the way, use the quoting in general when making your SQL strings. This is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check is a reserved word, you have to quote it. While you do it in your create statement, you forgot it in your insert statement.